Whats the best practice way to initialise a Redis pub/sub subscriber in a Rails app when it starts up?
I have a collection of Rails apps. They all have some sense of an "Organisation" model, we have a bit of a strange auth and centralized organisation database setup where those two things are not the same app. I want to be able to use Redis pub/sub on our app that also happens to be our source of truth for organisations so that when it merges organisations it puts out a message with some details about the merge. I want to allow other apps to subscribe with the pub/sub method to this channel to be allowed to know about merges and make changes however they like. I have all of this basically set up and working but I don't know the best way to instantiate the subscriber methods on the apps when they get deployed, it needs to happen automatically of course.
Should I have a class in config/initializers that starts a new thread and calls the redis.subscribe method?
Should I perform a Resque job from an initializer class that is in its own dedicated queue and has its own dedicated worker which then calls the redis.subscribe?
Are there other ideas of how I should do this? Or does this just not makes sense overall?
I haven't full tried either yet, I have just been fumbling around looking for recommendations.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

From what I can understand, your model could lead to a multiple subscriber, which is not very efficient. Assuming you pub all over the apps, having a dedicated subscriber machine to listen to these publish makes sense. If it is possible with your architecture ofcourse.
